# Objective-C can't see class declaration

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is for an online course project [Objective-C for Swift developers](https://eu.udacity.com/course/objective-c-for-swift-developers--ud1009). I created a command-line Objective-C project, and then add a class called `House` to my project using the dropdown New File > Cocoa Class menu. However, referencing the class in the main file does not work (getting "Use of unresolved identifier House" compile-time error):

*main.m* file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        House *myHouse = [[House alloc] init];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

House header file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface House : NSObject

@end
```

House implementation file:

```
#import "House.h"

@implementation House

@end
```

I've deleted the Derived Data folder and restarted the Xcode project with no success. Also, the House.m file in listed under the Compile Resources the project settings. This must be so simple. Why can't Xcode see the class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `#import "House.h"` in your `main.m`